# node-rsa working on codesandbox but not on my localhost

Tags: reactjs

I have some code which is importing `node-rsa` and performing simple encryption in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-panka-c4353y?file=/src/App.js:75-83). However when I copy this same code on my localhost it's generating a set of errors:

[image]
[image]

You can download the zip, `npm install` and `npm start` and you'll see the errors.

I tried importing the following packages but it's still not working like it's working on codesandbox, any help will be appreciated

```
npm install assert --save
npm install constants --save
npm install crypto --save
npm i crypto
npm install crypto-js
npm i crypto-browserify
npm i buffer
```

**UDPATE**
I got it working however much more confused now. In my localhost machine, I modified `package.json`, `react-scripts` from `5.0.1` to `4.0.3`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "keypair": "1.0.4",
    "loader-utils": "3.2.1",
    "node-rsa": "1.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
```

and suddenly it works!

I set react-scripts in codesandbox as `5.0.1` which is working in sandbox but not on my machine. How is this possible?